# URI-design random resource

Tags: rest, url-rewriting, uri

Lets say I have a site about animals and I have a collection as following:

```
/animals/
```

to return a specific animal you would do:

```
/animals/tiger
```

Now I want to design my uri to return a random animal. What is the best practices? Would that be by using a query parameter? Or by using:

```
/animals/random
```

But since this is a function that could be applied on various collections I would maybe put in on a resource of it's own? Like:

```
/random?type=animal
```

/James

Comment: This is a question of personal taste, really. If your site is centred around *animals* then it's fair to place GET RANDOM below /Animals/ in the namespace.